# Reading Data from XLSX in C# using ExcelDataReader v2.1 and writing to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I need to write a console application in C# reading data from XLSX and writing to SQL server using ExcelDataReader v2.1 .

I need to read the data in Cell D17,D18,D19 and drop to buying column in SQL.
And read Cell K17,K18,K19 and drop to /selling column in SQL
This is the SQL table query and database name is test1

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[code]
      ,[buying]
      ,[selling]
  FROM [test1].[dbo].[Currency]
```

This is a code i tried but it is not using ExcelDataReader v2.1. i need help to do it with ExcelDataReader v2.1

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExportToSQLServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.215;Initial Catalog=RECIPES2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();


                    ExecuteQueryWithoutResult(connection, "USE test1");

                    //Load XLS document
                    using (Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet())
                    {
                        document.LoadFromFile("SimpleReport.xls");
                        Worksheet worksheet = document.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                        for (int row = 0; row <= worksheet.UsedRangeRowMax; row++)
                        {
                            String insertCommand = string.Format("INSERT XlsTest VALUES('{0}','{1}')",
                           worksheet.Cell(row, 0).Value, worksheet.Cell(row, 1).Value);
                            ExecuteQueryWithoutResult(connection, insertCommand);
                        }
                    }

                    // Check the data successfully exported
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from XlsTest", connection))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Exported XLS data:");
                            Console.WriteLine();

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}  |  {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void ExecuteQueryWithoutResult(SqlConnection connection, string query)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```